# Trouble using MAX function with two GROUP BY statements

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, group-by

I first make a subquery to show the MAX values of (complete_dt-create_dt) grouped by every HOUR of the day. Then, I group by day, since I want to show the max value (of the grouped by hour max) for each day.

What I get is the MAX value of all days showed up in every row:

```
max(TIMELENGTH) |   DAY
210.5           |        16
210.5           |        17
210.5           |        27
```

This is the query I use, what am I doing wrong:

```
select max(hours.timelength) TimeLength, TO_CHAR(trunc(t.create_dt), 'DD') DAY   
FROM ORDERS t, 
     (select round(avg(24 * 3600 * (m.complete_dt-m.create_dt)),1) TimeLength
     from ORDERS m
     GROUP BY TRUNC(m.create_dt, 'HH')) hours  
where t.order_status_id in (80)
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(trunc(t.create_dt), 'DD')
```

Thank you,

Comment: You are not joining the two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might give you what you're after.

```
select max(hours.timelength) TimeLength, hours.Day   
FROM
 (
 select 
 round(avg(24 * 3600 * (m.complete_dt-m.create_dt)),1) TimeLength,
 TO_CHAR(trunc(t.create_dt), 'DD') Day,
 TRUNC(m.create_dt, 'HH') hours
 from ORDERS m
 where t.order_status_id in (80)
 GROUP BY TRUNC(m.create_dt, 'HH'), TO_CHAR(trunc(t.create_dt), 'DD')
 ) hours  
GROUP BY hours.Day
```

Your original query had no join between t and hours

Comment: Hmm, thanks a lot. When I run it I face an error though: FROM keyword not found where expected. (and the last parentheses of line 7 [right before hours] is highlighted with the error. I tried to fix it but nothing.

Comment: Do you know why this one works and the other doesn't? The other one would have done a cross join, meaning if ORDERS has 10,000 rows it, your select would have produced 100,000,000 rows. Your DBA wouldn't be happy with that! Anyway good luck.

Comment: I dont get why you group by day twice though. Shouldn't that somehow be redundant? Thanks for the answer, it helped me a lot ;)

Comment: What happens if you take it out of the inner subtable? You can't group by it in the outer table! Normally it would be redundant but since you want to find an AVG by an hour then find a SUM by a day it is definitely not redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
select max(hours.timelength) as TimeLength, trunc(firstcreate_dt) as DAY   
FROM ORDERS t, 
     (select round(avg(24 * 3600 * (m.complete_dt-m.create_dt)),1) TimeLength,
             min(create_dt) as firstcreate_dt
      from ORDERS m
      where t.order_status_id in (80)
      GROUP BY TRUNC(m.create_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH')
     ) hours  
GROUP BY trunc(firstcreate_dt)
```

You do not want to use `to_char(. . . , 'DD')` because that only returns the day of the month.

Also, in the expression `to_char(trunc(t.create_dt), 'DD')` the `trunc()` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, actually I needed only the days :) thats why the to_char(..., 'DD'). Thanks for the trunc redudancy, I'll take it out. Though I see a difference between your answer and @ElectricLlama answer. He also groups by Days inside the subquery, I'm not sure if this brings any difference.

Comment: @hoesta . . . The two are equivalent.  He groups separately by days and hours.  I group by one field that contains days and hours (these should have the same performance as well).  That solution explicitly pulls the date from the subquery; this calculates it based on the min creation date.  That version is fine, except for the days-of-month.  Going by just days-of-month doesn't seem like the right way to go in most cases.